# How to create a custom POST request-body in SwaggerUI

Tags: java, httprequest, swagger, swagger-ui

Im trying to get SwaggerUI look properly working for me. I have a bunch of POST Methods and SwaggerUI does already generate a response and request body in the Web-UI, however the request body is not correct. How do i create a custom request-body for my POST Methods?

The **SpringFoxConfig** is

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.ResponseMessage;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                //.globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, ImmutableList.of(new ResponseMessage(200, "Some global OK message",null)))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()            
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo()); 
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("RESTlike API",
                "An Api to call functions",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "");
    }
}
```

**For Example**
The schema displayed in the UI is

```
{
"da": "MD5",
  "data": {
    "value": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is not **the correct input** the and would throw an error.
The **correct input** would in this example be:

```
{
"da": "MD5",
"data": "String"
}
```

Where does the data the schema has come from and how can i change it/override it.

The corresponding **method** would be

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/digest")
public StringWrapper digestData(@RequestBody DigestDataContainer params) throws IOException {
    return new StringWrapper(//code);
}
```

DigestDataContainer simply contains a bytearray 'data' and an enum 'da'

**Edit**

Okay, i found out why the generated response body is wrong, swagger determinates the parameters of the request body by looking at the public parameters and **all** getters. Since i do not have only getters related to parameters in my methods there are too much displayed in the UI.
You can prevent a parameter being shown in the UI by annotating it with

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
```

However, i don't have i unique body for every method of mine, i have grouped some of them, which leads to the generated request-body in the UI not being accurate to the method it is in. Hence i want to not show the body at all in the UI.

- Is there a way to disable the model schema for the request?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (like for me) way is to use DTO objects.

In your case instead of your `digestData(@RequestBody DigestDataContainer params)` just use method

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/digest")
public StringWrapper digestData(@RequestBody DigestDataContainerDTO ddcDTO) throws IOException {

    DigestDataContainer ddc = new DigestDataContainer(ddcDTO);

    // process your DigestDataContainer object as before
}
```

where `DigestDataContainerDTO` is

```
public class DigestDataContainerDTO {
    private String da;
    private String data;
    // getters/setters
}
```

and `DigestDataContainer(ddcDTO)` builds `DigestDataContainer` object from fields of `DigestDataContainerDTO`.

Comment: As i only have one controller in my example, this leads to the same situation as before. '.any()' simply selects all handlers, while basePackage lets you select specific ones i guess.
I've updated the question with a more concrete example. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please, add your REST method declaration too

Comment: added an example method

Comment: DigestDataContainer too :-) I guess, it does not contains two string fields, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, i found out why the model-schema is wrong and updated the question.
Do you happen to know how to disable it?